# Why the ouput of nn.Embeddings(vocab_size, dim) chnages on re-running the code for same input string?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, nlp, word-embedding

I am trying to understand how word embeddings are generated, I've been reading that 1-hot encoded vector is used and it servers as a lookup table but, I want to print that and see, how can I do that.  When I am doing the following:

```
 self.embeddings = nn.Embedding(vocab_size, dim)
 print('embed',self.embeddings.weight)
```

I am getting different results when I re-run the code for same input string/vocab_size and same dim.

I want to know why this happens and how are those weight values calulated? What equation/fucntions is used to get these values? Is any function like softmax etc used to get the weights?

Comment: The initial weights are random. If you want something deterministic, you can set a seed.

Comment: Ok alright!
So basically after these random weights (to vectorize word) we apply a forward layer and softmax to get the final embeddings?